# Module variable not accessable from all files

Tags: ruby, module

I have a ruby application that stretches across a module: call it `Bacon`

```
module Bacon
    @@foo = nil
    def self.set_foo(info)
        @@foo = SomeClass.new(info)
    end
    def self.get_foo
        return @@foo
    end

    class SomeClass
        attr_accessor :info
        def initialize(info)
            @info = info
        end
    end
end

Bacon::set_foo("Secret!")
puts Bacon::get_foo.info
```

and that works all fine. However if I want to access `Bacon::get_foo` from a different file using `require_relative` and initiating an `OtherClass` instance as follows:

```
module Bacon
    class OtherClass
        def initialize
            puts Bacon::get_foo.info
        end
    end
end
```

I get:

> undefined method `info' for nil:NilClass

I was under the impression that, when using a module across multiple files, all the variables and values were shared between them. After all the `OtherClass` can see the method `get_foo`, just that there is no value stored in `@@foo`.

Can someone explain this? If there is a better way to do it (have a class instance accessible throughout a module).

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Did you add `require_relative 'bacon'` in other_class.rb ?

Comment: Well...first, when I do require_relative 'bacon' in the other file it causes the intial file to run twice. Is there a way around that?

Secondly...doing so I now get a different error:

'uninitialized constant Bacon::OtherClass (NameError)'